# How to validate on button click

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am new to HTML,JQuery.so not getting how to solve my problem.

My problem is:

In my website i have to provide a `username` Validation.Here validation is checking entered username with mysql database.

if database contain username then the pop should come to saying that `username is already exist` please enter alternate.

i am using `Xampp`, php.

what i tried is:

```
 <label id="showlabel">UserName</label>
         <input type="text"  name="user" id="user" >
        <input type="button" name="checkuser"   id="checkuser" value="Validated" onclick="test();">


function test()

{
    /* check user is already exist in database */

}
```

I dont no how to do.

Please can any one guide me on this.

Comment: if you want to do it by jquery you have to use ajax.

Comment: use ajax it will solve your problem.

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX to send an asynchronous request to a PHP script that checks for the existence of the specified username then sends an appropriate response. The success callback handler for the AJAX request will need to work with that response in some way.

Comment: Read this: [PHP Login script tutorial](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html) and add AJAX to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this by using ajax like this

**HTML**

```
<label id="showlabel">UserName</label>
<input type="text"  name="user" id="user" value="">
<input type="button" name="checkuser"   id="checkuser" value="Validated" onclick="test();">

<div id="user_status"></div>
```

**AJAX**

modify your test function like this

```
<script>
function test()
{   
    var username = document.getElementById('user').value;
    var url = "check_user.php?username="+username;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

            var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if(xmlhttp.responseText!='')
            {
                document.getElementById('user_status').innerHTML =result ;
            }   
        }
    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);

    xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

**PHP** : check_user.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_REQUEST['username'])
{
  echo "please set username";
  exit;
}
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];

$username = trim($username);


if($username=="")
{
    echo "please enter username";
}
else
{
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo "Username is exists in database";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Username is not exists in database";
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## HTML ##
 <label id="showlabel">UserName</label>
             <input type="text"  name="user" id="user" onblur="test(this);" >
            <span id="servermessage"/>

## JQuery ##

function test(sender)
{
 if ($.trim($(sender).val()).length) {
$.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                async: true,
                url: "checkusername.php", //In that php file check the value is unique or not in DB
                data: {username: $(sender).val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data)
                       $('#servermessage').text("This username is already taken! Try another.");
                    else
                       $('#servermessage').text('Username is available.');
                }
            });
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that checks your user name availability on every time you enter an character
You need two files

1. index.html
2. check.php

code for html

1. index.html

   ```
           <html>
           <head>
           <title>USER CHECK</title>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">

           $(document).ready(function(){

                   $('#fb').load('check.php').show();

            $('#username_input').keyup(function(){
                $('#fb').html('<p>Searching...</p>')
                var dataString = $("#f1").serialize();
                   //alert (dataString);return false; 
                 $.ajax({  
                       type: "POST",  
                       url: "check.php",
                       data: dataString, 
                       success:function(result)
                       {
                           $('#fb').html(result).show();
                       }
                });
                    return false;
              });
            });
           </script>
           </head>
           <body>
               <form id='f1' name='f1' action="">
               <label>UserName</label>
               <input type="text" name="username" id="username_input"><span id="fb"></span>
               </form>
           </body>
           </html>
   ```
2. check.php code

   ```
   <?php 
   $db = new mysqli('HOST NAME','USER NAME','PASSWORD','DATABASE NAME');
   if($db->connect_errno)
   {
       die("DATABASE ERROR");
   }
   if(isset($_POST['username']))
   {
       $uname = $_POST['username'];
   }
   if(!empty($uname))
   {
   $query= ("select * from yourtablename where username='$uname'");
   $result=$db->query($query);
   $count = $result->num_rows;
   if($count == 0 )
   {
       echo "available";
   }
   else if($count == 1)
   {
       echo "not available";
   }
   }
   ?>
   ```

   it will shows "available" if user name is available otherwise "not available"